# Offensive single-noun term for "indecisive person"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, pejorative-language, offensive-language

I'm looking for an offensive single-noun term for "indecisive person," preferably short and cutting. Something along the lines of "nitwit" for "foolish person"; but now instead of "foolish," try "indecisive." No adjective synonyms, please.

Comment: In British English, "ditherer". I think it has a different meaning in the US - I'm not certain.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4842/2085).

Comment: This line of questioning is unseemly. I hope you don't think we are the supermarket of insults.

Comment: "Ditherer" was the first word that came to mind for me (in the US).  (But "waffler" is probably a hair more idiomatic.)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on context, you could use **"a fence-sitter"**

> - [fence-sitting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fence-sitting) - "a state of indecision or neutrality with respect to conflicting positions"

or **"vacillating"** (one who vacillates)

> - [vacillate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vacillate) -  implies prolonged hesitation from inability to reach a firm decision.  **He vacillated until events were out of control.**

or **"a shilly–shally person"**

> - [shilly–shally](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shilly-shally) -   (adj) irresolute, vacillating

Comment: i think fence-sitter is short and sweet and even a Chinese can relate. In Chinese we call wall-sitter the kind of People who sit on the fence/wall, watching, and be prepared to lean to the winning side when a trend becomes visible. same?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, if you called the person a **"waffler"**, you'd probably be understood.

Comment: I think you'd almost certainly be understood, at least by me and the two people nearest me (in the US, for what it's worth).

Comment: In (at least some of) the UK you'd be misunderstood. To *waffle* is to talk at length with little clarity or purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A **ditherer**. This has been suggested in the comments, and is the right word.

Answer (score 0):

The term *[wuss](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/wuss)* is somewhat broader

> A weak or ineffectual person (often used as a general term of abuse).

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

But it is often used to describe somewhat who is fearful to commit or take action.

Comment: Perhaps "flake" or "ditz" would work too.

Answer (score 0):

**Procrastinator** is a term that springs to mind.  Useful to describe a person that is too busy concerning themselves with the pros and cons of a solution than actually implementing it

Comment: Welcome to the site @Andrew! You can improve your answer with a link to an online dictionary and a dictionary definition.